# Style CheckBox text with inlines

Tags: c#, silverlight, checkbox, textblock, inlines

I am trying to style text on a page that contains TextBlocks and TextBlocks as the content of CheckBoxes

I want to do something like this (where textBlock is the TextBlock contained within the CheckBox - or anything that inherits from System.Windows.Controls.Control)

```
textBlock.Inlines.Add("unstyledText");
textBlock.Inlines.Add(new Run { Text = "yellowBoldText ", Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow), FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold });
textBlock.Inlines.Add("unstyledText");
```

This works on the TextBlocks that are not inside a CheckBox. If they are inside a CheckBox, the TextBlock's Text property will change (ie. `textBlock.Text == "unstyledText yellowBoldText unstyledText"` returns true), but the text in the CheckBox will not visually change.

Is there anyway to get the TextBlocks inside a CheckBox to behave the same way as the other TextBlocks?

Comment: at that point is that a State property that you can check against if so you may need to set it from there..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `CheckBox`'s style must be overriding the `TextBlock`'s style in its States.

Instead of having a `TextBlock` with `Run`s as a content of your `CheckBox`, try adding a horizontal `StackPanel` with `TextBlock`s.

If the layout is not rendered as you would expect (for example WordWrap) try editing the style of the `ComboBox`.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, this worked. I changed my XAML from
<CheckBox Content="text"/>
to
<CheckBox>
     <TextBlock Text="text"/>
</CheckBox>